# Add FQDN to log messages in SLF4J/Logback

Tags: java, scala, logging, slf4j, logback

I am using Logback to feed data into Logstash via a [TCP appender](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder#tcp).

The problem I have is that I can get the *unqualified hostname* (e.g. *myhostname*) of the application creating logs out-of-the-box, but I can't see a way to get the FQDN (e.g. *myhostname.mydomain.com*) to be logged instead.

I can see [here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) that Logback comes with the HOSTNAME variable already configured in its Context, but I can't *expand* that to get the fqdn instead...

**Edit:**
What I need is a way, **from the logback configuration itself**, to get hold og this info. Unfortunately, I can't modify the code that will emit the log message itself.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try and resolve your name to IP address or to FQDN. Use InetAddress class and its static method [getByName(String name)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName-java.lang.String-) to try and resolve your name. After that you can retrieve from it IP address or FQDN by method "public String getCanonicalHostName()"

Comment: see my latest edit. I clarified that I actually need to do this from the config, as I can't modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [logback documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html##hostname), HOSTNAME is automatically defined as variable within [context scope](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#scopes) as is available from within the configuration file.

The fully qualified domain is not defined automatically. However, you could define it on the fly with a custom [property definer](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#definingPropsOnTheFly).